# Storing for loop result to push into HTML

Tags: javascript, function, for-loop, innerhtml, getelementsbyclassname

**EDIT: Solved. After the helpful people here helped me solve this I realised this issue was to do with my `getElementsByClassName` selector. Sorry if the title is misleading. The original question is below.**

I am getting the expected results from this function's `for` loop, but I can't get them to print to the HTML.

Could anybody help point out what I'm missing? A point in the right direction would do, I can do some legwork myself.

Any advice is much appreciated.

*HTML:*

```
<input type="text" name="searchString" class="searchString">

<span class="longestWordInput"></span>
<span class="longestWordCountInput"></span>

<button class="generate">Generate</button>
```

*JavaScript:*

```
function longestWordFunc() {
  var stringSplit = document.querySelector(".searchString").value.split(" ");

  let longestWordCount = 0;
  let longestWord = "";

  for(var i = 0; i < stringSplit.length; i++) {
    if(stringSplit[i].length > longestWordCount) {

      longestWordCount = stringSplit[i].length; 
      longestWord = stringSplit[i]
    }
  }

  //Logging expected result
  console.log(longestWordCount)
  console.log(longestWord)

  //Print to HTML not working
  document.getElementsByClassName("longestWordInput").innerHTML = longestWord;
  document.getElementsByClassName("longestWordCountInput").innerHTML = longestWordCount;
};

document.querySelector(".generate").addEventListener("click", longestWordFunc);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that [getElementsByClassName()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) returns a NodeList (an array-like structure containing all elements with the specified class name) instead of a single element.

You can access your single span element like this

```
document.getElementsByClassName("longestWordInput")[0].innerHTML = longestWord;
```

or you could use [querySelector()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) instead

```
document.querySelector(".longestWordInput").innerHTML = longestWord;
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi I believe  you need to use getElementsByClassName like the below

```
document.getElementsByClassName("longestWordInput")[0].innerHTML = longestWord;
document.getElementsByClassName("longestWordCountInput")[0].innerHTML = longestWordCount;
```